# CSV Writer truncates characters in sequence in Excel 2013

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, text, excel-2013

I have an interesting situation with Python's csv module. I have a function that takes specific lines from a text file and writes them to csv file:

```
import os
import csv

def csv_save_use(textfile, csvfile):
    with open(textfile, "rb") as text:
        for line in text:
            line=line.strip()
            with open(csvfile, "ab") as f:            
                if line.startswith("# Online_Resource"):   
                    write = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel',
                                       delimiter='\t',
                                       lineterminator="\t",
                                       )
                    write.writerow([line.lstrip("# ")])

                if line.startswith("##"):
                    write = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel',
                                       delimiter='\t',
                                       lineterminator="\t",
                                       )
                    write.writerow([line.lstrip("# ")])
```

Here is a sample of some strings from the original text file:

```
# Online_Resource: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/
## Corg%    percent organic carbon,,,%,,paleoceanography,,,N
```

What is really bizarre is the final csv file looks good, except the characters in the first column only (those with the `#` originally) partially "overwrite" each other when I try to manually delete some characters from the cell:

[image: Result]

Oddly enough, too, there seems to be no formula to how the characters get jumbled each time I try to delete some after running the script. I tried encoding the csv file as unicode to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: can you try `csv.writer(f, dialect='excel',
                                       delimiter='\t')` without other params that are _really_ exotic. Line terminator and delimiter must be different. And the quotechar is better set to double quotes.

Comment: Why do you keep opening the output file? Open it once at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using the same character for the column delimiter and the line terminator. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: with your current code processing the input as a simple text file, it's not possible that the commas are transformed to cells. Are you sure you're showing us the actual version of the code?

Comment: Yeah, this is the actual code. That's why I had the exotic pairing of delimiter = lineterminator, as it seemingly "worked" for the comma structure, though it doesn't really work, as we're seeing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I can't imagine why you deleted your answer -- it covered about 50% of the OP's problems

Comment: @JohnMachin you're nice. That pushed my to edit my answer and propose a better, fixed code. Objective: 100% of the problems covered :)

Comment: @JohnMachin Thank you for your input. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've selected excel dialect but you overrode it with weird parameters:

- You're using TAB as separator *and* line terminator, which creates a 1-line CSV file. Close enough to "truncated" to me
- Also `quotechar` shouldn't be a space.

This conveyed a nice side-effect as you noted: the csv module actually splits the lines according to commas!

The code is inefficient and error-prone: you're opening the file in append mode in the loop and create a new csv writer each time. Better done outside the loop.

Also, comma split must be done by hand now. So even better: use `csv` module to read the file as well. My fix proposal for your routine:

```
import os
import csv

def csv_save_use(textfile, csvfile):
  with open(textfile, "rU") as text, open(csvfile, "wb") as f:
    write = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel',
                       delimiter='\t')
    reader = csv.reader(text, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        if not row:
            continue  # skip possible empty rows            
        if row[0].startswith("# Online_Resource"):
            write.writerow([row[0].lstrip("# ")])

        elif row[0].startswith("##"):
            write.writerow([row[0].lstrip("# ")]+row[1:]) # write row, stripping the first item from hashes
```

Note that the file isn't properly displayed in excel unless to *remove* `delimiter='\t` (reverts back to default comma)

Also note that you need to replace `open(csvfile, "wb") as f` by `open(csvfile, "w",newline='') as f` for Python 3.

here's how the output looks now (note that the empty cells are because there are several commas in a row)

[image]

Comment: When I only keep the default parameters the csv module writes the string to one cell (including the commas).

Comment: check my new proposal

Comment: Et voila! Thank you very much, Jean-Francois. Your code is much more intuitive. I am fairly new to Python for these tasks so thank you very much for the csv tutorial, essentially.

Comment: "splitting on commas" works only if the input doesn't contain any fields that contain the delimiter (comma) or quotechar ... the whole point of the csv module is that it does the tricky bits for you

Comment: @JohnMachin Yeah, that makes sense now. I think I was trying to do too much, as I didn't know certain functionalities of the csv module.

Comment: I imagine the downvote is for not using csv module for the input. Ok Will edit, but not now.

Comment: John is saying that your split will work so long as any inputs don't have commas in them. For me, this will never be an issue, but could be for someone else's text file.

Comment: so much effort to get a downvote :) I sometimes got 6 or 7 upvotes for less researched answers... Anyway, thanks for accepting it.

Comment: Jean, I changed the reader input to "text" instead of "textfile". I receive an error, though, that the first row element ([0]) is out of range when I run the script. Could opening the text file in rU mode have something to do with it?

Comment: I dunno, not very familiar with universal newlines mode. But see my edit. I added a protection against empty rows.

Comment: Yes, that works. I kept the "rU" mode to be on the safe side of things. Thanks again for everything. Merci bcp. :)

Answer (score 1):

more problems:

1. `line=line.strip(" ")` removes leading and trailing spaces. It doesn't remove `\r` or `\n` ... try `line=line.strip()` which removes leading and trailing whitespace
2. you get all your line including commas in one cell because you haven't split it up somehow ... like using a `csv.reader` instance. See here:
   https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader
3. `str.lstrip` non-default arg is treated as a set of characters to be removed, so `'## '` has the same effect as `'# '`. if `guff.startswith('## ')` then do `guff = guff[3:]` to get rid of the unwanted text
4. It is not very clear at all what the sentence containing "bizarre" means. We need to see exactly what is in the output csv file. Create a small test file with 3 records (1) with `'# Online_Resource'` (2) with `"## "` (3) none of the above, run your code, and show the output, like this:

`print repr(open('testout.csv', 'rb').read())`

Comment: Hi John, (1) and (3) were oversights. Fixed. (4) The output is the screenshot in the OP. I changed the code to `write = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t',)` as Jean-Francois said, and the output is: `carbonate% percent calcium carbonate,,,%,,paleoceanography,,,N` per cell.

Comment: @SamuelLockshin-NOAAAffilia (2) I added a link to the docs for csv.writer (4) For debug purposes we want to look at exactly what's in your output csv file; that can't be done by reverse-engineering from an excel screen shot

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. Jean-Francois provided an exact solution. It was necessary to remove the delimiter and split the lines before passing them into csv.writer. It was better to take the csv file out of the loop, too. This all makes much more sense intuitively. Thanks for pointing out my errors.